# why is the iterator not initialized in this code

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, copy-constructor

In the code below, Class A has a vector of ints. Class B inherits from A and has an iterator to the vector. The constructor of B initializes the iterator of B. But when we print, we get garbage. Why does the cout in main print garbage? Am I missing something?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A { 
public:
    A() {}
    A(const A& copyFrom) : intList(copyFrom.intList) {} //copy constructor
    virtual ~A() {}

    void populateList() 
    {
        for(int i=10; i<100; i++) 
        {
            intList.push_back(i);
        }
    }

protected:
    std::vector<int> intList;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() : A() {}
    B(const A& a) : A(a), intIt(intList.begin()) 
    {
        std::cout << "constructor with base class param called" << std::endl;
    }

    B(const B& b) : A(b), intIt(intList.begin()) //copy constructor
    { 
        std::cout << "copy constructor called" << std::endl;
    } 


    std::vector<int>::iterator intIt;
};

int main() {
A a;
a.populateList();
B b ;
b = B(a);
std::cout << *b.intIt << std::endl; //prints garbage. why?
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `b = B(a)` separated from declaration is *assignment*, not copy construction. This is one of the confusing things about C++:

```
Foo x(y);      // copy-construction
Foo x = y;     // also copy-construction, equivalent to the above

Foo x; x = y;  // default-construction followed by assignment, different
               // (and possibly less efficient) than the above
```

Failing to define an assignment operator will create a default one that performs member-wise assignment. This is OK for the `intList` member, but the assigned `intIt` will keep pointing to the old list, which in your case belongs to the temporary reference to `B` created by the `B(a)` expression. As soon as this reference is destroyed (which is at the end of the outermost expression), its `intList` is destroyed and the iterator becomes invalid.

In other words, `B b; b = B(a)` is equivalent to:

```
B b;         // constructor
{
  B tmp(a);  // copy constructor
  b = tmp;   // member-wise assignment
  // at this point, b.intList is a copy of tmp.intList, but b.intIt
  // points to the beginning of tmp.intList, not to the beginning of
  // b.intList
}
// tmp is destroyed and b.intIt now points to the beginning of a deleted list
```

It is your responsibility to define an assignment operator that maintains the invariant of `intIt` referring to an element in `intList`; for example:

```
B& operator=(const B& rhs)
{
    intList = rhs.intList;
    intIt = intList.begin() + (rhs.intIt - rhs.intList.begin());
    std::cout << "assignment called" << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

Also note that all iterators into the vector are invalidated when you change the size of the vector, even if you only append with `push_back()`. So `populateList()`, and other methods that can change the size of the vector should be overridden in `B` to also recalculate `intIt`. For these reasons it would be a better idea to avoid using an iterator and simply store the position into the vector, and have a function that returns `intList.begin() + pos`, thus creating an iterator on-demand that is guaranteed to be valid. Then you wouldn't need to define neither a copy-constructor nor an assignment operator, as the compiler-supplied defaults would work just fine.

Comment: `Since the intList in B is never populated`: - Won't `A(a),` in the constructor copy the vector from a to the object being constructed, and then `intIt(intList.begin())` would initialize `intIt` to `intList.begin()` from B's own instance of the vector?

Comment: @hash You are right. The real reason is that the default assignment operator performs a member-wise assignment of the iterator, which makes it point to the list created by the `B(a)` temporary that is immediately destroyed, invalidating the iterator.

Comment: You're right. I explicitly defined the operator overload for `=` and initialized the iterator. It worked. Thanks!

Comment: @hash Note that you probably want the iterator to point to the appropriate element of the vector, as shown in the latest edit.

Comment: Also, shouldn't there be a return statement in the operator overload?

Comment: @hash Yup, fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

```
B b ;
b = B(a); //the copy constructor of B is not called here. Why?
```

The operation in that line is **assignment**, not copy constructor. The copy constructor would be:

```
B b = someotherB;
```

Note that semantically this is also copy-constructing:

```
B b = B(a);
```

But the compiler will more often than not elide the copy contruction by creating `B(a)` in place of `b`.

Comment: I understand that the constructor with base class argument will be called, but that does not explain why *b.intIt is garbage. That is my main concern.

Comment: @user4815162342: Sorry if it sounded condescending, it was not the intention (and I am removing the comment), but it is a very **important** feature of the question to actually ask the right things. *Why is the copy constructor not called?* Because you are not calling it

Comment: Sometimes it's just not that simple. For all the OP new, the copy constructor was **called** (to create the temporary reference). The OP was unaware that its work was subsequently corrupted by the compiler-generated assignment and asked about the thing he *did* directly observe, the garbage in `*.bintIt` - both in the question and in the above comment. If he had known enough about the problem to "ask the right things," he wouldn't need our help in the first place. Dealing with questions by people that don't understand the underlying problem is part of the challenge (and fun) of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The Copy construction will not be called because you are not assigning object of same class

```
b = B(a); //the copy constructor of B is not called here. Why?
```

in above code below constructor will be called because you are passing object of type A

```
B(const A& a) : A(a), intIt(intList.begin()) 
{
    std::cout << "constructor with base class param called" << std::endl;
}
```

Iterator value will not be usable because you are not initializing it

```
std::cout << *(b.intIt) << std::endl; //prints garbage. why?
```

you need to initalize it

```
 std::vector<X>::iterator iter;  //no particular value
 iter = some_vector.begin();  //iter is now usable
```